# Custom checkstyle configuration ignores standard rules?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I'm setting up the code style checking for my project. There are some standard rules I want to customize. For that, I created a file named `checkstyle.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" 
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="SuppressionFilter">
        <property name="file" value="${checkstyle.suppressions.file}"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="HiddenField">
            <property name="ignoreSetter" value="true"/>
            <property name="ignoreConstructorParameter" value="true"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

In project's `pom.xml`, I configured maven checkstyle plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>checkstyle</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <consoleOutput>${checkstyle.printErrors}</consoleOutput>
        <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
        <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now, only the `HiddenField` check is applied, all the other checks from `sun_checks.xml` are turned off. If I turn the custom checkstyle.xml off in plugin settings, the standard checks are applied again.

Question is, how to apply the standard checks, modifying the settings for one or some of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do that by copying the [standard configuration file](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-6.11.2/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml) locally as your own *checkstyle.xml*, then modify it.

Be sure to use the one that fits your version of Checkstyle. The Maven Checkstyle Plugin 2.17 you are using uses Checkstyle 6.11.2 ([reference](http://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/checkstyle-compatibility-matrix.html)). Just modify the version number in the URL of the configuration file to download the correct version.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Although I find it not very intuitive or maintainable :-)